# Need to call logout call on browser close - In angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, browser, rxjs, angular7

Below is my logout call:

```js
logoutClick() {
    let response: any;
    this._httpService.fetch(SERVICE_URL.LOGOUT, 'get').subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            response = res;
        },
        (error: any) => {
            this._commonService.showLoader = false;
            this._cookieService.delete('tokenId');
            this._cookieService.delete('userInfo');
        },
        () => {
            debugger;
            console.log('abgffgdfgdg');
            this._cookieService.delete('tokenId');
            this._cookieService.delete('userInfo');
            this._commonService.showLoader = false;
        },
    );
}
```

This needs to be called on browser close,

Tried below :

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.onLogoutClick()
});
```

Not working as expected,
Using angular version 7

Comment: 1) `that.onLogoutClick()` typo: `that.` -> `this.` 2) 3th parameter in subscribe will run if "completed".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your are using the Angular httpClient request which is an asynchronous request.

You cannot perform an asynchronous event inside the browser close event.

Try a syn request using:

1)**XMLHttpRequest**

Note: The latest Chrome does not support it now - [Read here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912)

2)**Async/await**